# Why is the map method not displaying my div content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm currently trying to create a web app with React that prompts a user with a form to enter some inputs. On submit, the code creates an object "teammate" and is then pushed to an array "Team". After I then wish to cycle through my array with the map method and display all my teammate objects on a card each. I cannot figure out why line 94 of my App.js is not displaying my array. Please help any advice would be much appreciated.

```
import logo from './Nemo.jpg';
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Card.css'

const App = () =>  {

  const NavBar = () => {
    return(
        <>
        <nav>
            <div style={{display: 'inline-flex'}}>
            <a href='index.js'>
            <img src={logo} width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none"></img>
            </a>
            <h1>Metric Dashboard</h1>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <br></br>

        </>
    )
  }



const MyForm = () =>{

    //Define Team array
    const [Team,setTeam]  = useState([]);

    //Function used for submit
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        let teammate = {
            myId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
            myUserName: document.getElementById('user').value,
            mySweepName: document.getElementById('SweepName').value,
            mySweepDate: document.getElementById('SweepDate').value,
            mySweepCases: document.getElementById('SweepCases').value,
            update: function() {
                this.mySweepDate = document.getElementById('SweepDate').value;
                this.mySweepCases = document.getElementById('SweepCases').value;
                this.mySweepName = document.getElementById('SweepName').value;
            }

            

        }
        console.log(teammate)
        if(Team.length === 0 ){ //If array is empty
            console.log("This array is empty")
            Team.push(teammate)
            console.log("Array is no longer empty")
        }

        //If not empty checks if the user submits with the same sweep name. If same, update and not push to array
        else if(Team.length !== 0 ){ 
            console.log("This Array is not empty")
            for(let i = 0; i < Team.length; i++){
                if(Team[i].mySweepName === document.getElementById('SweepName') && Team[i].myUserName === document.getElementById('user').value){
                    console.log("Teammate Updated")
                    document.forms[0].reset()
                    return(Team[i].update())
                }
            }
            //If not empty and no duplicates, push object to array
            Team.push(teammate)
        }
        console.log(Team)
        document.forms[0].reset()
}
    return(
        <>
        <form> SWEEP
            <br/>
                Name: 
                <select id="user">
                <option value="default">Select your name</option>
                    <option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
                    <option value="Plain Jane">Plain Jane</option>
                    <option value="Mike Jones">Mike Jones</option>
                </select><br/>
                Name of Sweep:
                <input type='name'placeholder='Name of Sweep' id="SweepName" /><br/>
                Date:
                <input type='date' placeholder='Data' id="SweepDate"/><br/>
                Cases: 
                <input type="number" min="0" placeholder='# of cases' id="SweepCases"/>
            <br/>
            <input className='mySubmit' type="submit" onClick= {handleSubmit}/><br/><br/>
        </form>
        <div className='cardContainer'>
                {Team.map((item) =>(
                    <ul key={item.myId} className='sweepCard'>
                        <li>{item.myUserName}</li>
                        <li>Sweep Name: {item.mySweepName}</li>
                        <li>Sweep Date: {item.mySweepDate}</li>
                        <li>Sweep Cases: {item.mySweepCases}</li>
                    </ul>
                ))}
            </div>
        </>

    )
}

  return (
    <div className='App'>
        <div className='NavBar_Component'>
            <NavBar/>
        </div>
        <div className='Display_comps'>
            <div className='tryAgain'>
                 <MyForm/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

In my debugging I saw that my run reaches line 94 in my App.js but never begins the Team.map iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the way you are updating the Team state array. In React, you should not directly modify the state variable (in this case, Team) using methods like push, as it doesn't trigger a re-render of the component, and React won't recognize the state update.

To fix this, you should use the setTeam function provided by the useState hook to update the state array properly. The setTeam function will update the state and trigger a re-render of the component, ensuring that the new data is displayed.

handleSubmit function:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const newTeammate = {
    myId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
    myUserName: document.getElementById('user').value,
    mySweepName: document.getElementById('SweepName').value,
    mySweepDate: document.getElementById('SweepDate').value,
    mySweepCases: document.getElementById('SweepCases').value,
  };

  if (Team.length === 0) {
    console.log('This array is empty');
    setTeam([newTeammate]); // Use setTeam to update the state array
    console.log('Array is no longer empty');
  } else {
    console.log('This Array is not empty');
    const duplicateIndex = Team.findIndex(
      (item) =>
        item.mySweepName === newTeammate.mySweepName &&
        item.myUserName === newTeammate.myUserName
    );

    if (duplicateIndex !== -1) {
      console.log('Teammate Updated');
      const updatedTeam = [...Team];
      updatedTeam[duplicateIndex] = newTeammate;
      setTeam(updatedTeam);
    } else {
      //If not empty and no duplicates, push object to array
      setTeam((prevTeam) => [...prevTeam, newTeammate]);
    }
  }
  console.log(Team);
  document.forms[0].reset();
};
```

By using the setTeam function and passing the updated state as a new array (or a modified copy of the previous state), you ensure that the component re-renders with the correct data, and the Team.map iteration will display the updated array elements.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had little knowledge on useState and tried to avoid but never knew array needed to be used like this. Ill go back and re-read up on it!